# Reducer is acting weird

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Going straight to the problem.
Every time I create a new room with a new user, the application works just fine. But, as soon as I try adding a new user to an existing room, I lose all the previous users in that very room.

The code is available at - https://codesandbox.io/embed/xenodochial-tree-w75r8

Suppose I were to add two user(max and payne) to a brand new room called cool, I expect the output to be as shown.

FROM ROOM :

```
chatData:
  cool:
  message: {}
  users: Array(2)
      0: "max"
      1: "payne"
      length: 2
      proto: Array(0)
      proto: Object
  cricket: {users: Array(3), messages: Array(2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to copy the previous state that you had inside the users array before appending the new value. That's why you lose all your previous users.

```
case "EXISTING_ROOM_NEW_USER":
  return {
    ...initState,
    [action.payload.roomname]: {
      users: [...initState[action.payload.roomname].users, action.payload.username],
      message: {}
    }
  };
```